# Unsafe, reflection access vs toCharArray (performance)

Tags: java, performance

JDK9 team puts effort into helping us removing non-public dependencies (using `jdeps`). I am using `Unsafe` class for faster access to `String`s inner `char` array - without creating new char array. If I want to drop dependency on `Unsafe` class, I would need to load it dynamically and call `Unsafe.getObject` and other methods using reflection.

Now I wonder the performances: now when I use reflection with `Unsafe`, how this matches the `String.toCharArray` performances? Would it make sense to keep using `Unsafe`?

I assume JDK >= 7.

EDIT

Yes, I totally know that everyone can write these tests using eg JMH; but it takes a lot of time to measure with different inputs and different VM versions (7,8). So I wonder if someone already did this; as many libraries are using the `Unsafe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is a chance that there will be no backing `char[]` array at all in Java 9 version of `String`, see [JEP 254](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254). That is, `toCharArray()` will be your only option.
2. Generally you should never use `Unsafe` APIs unless you are absolutely sure it is neccessary. But since you are asking this question, I guess you are not. On my laptop, `toCharArray()` completes in 25 *nanoseconds* for 100-chars string, i.e. I could call this 40 million times a second! Do you really have such kind of workloads?
3. If absolutely needed, use [MethodHandles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#unreflectGetter-java.lang.reflect.Field-) instead of both Reflection and Unsafe. MethodHandles are as fast as direct field access, but unlike `Unsafe` they are *public*, *supported* and *safe* API.

Comment: Just a note: its not just calling `toCharArray()`; its also creating more waste; hence more GC; etc. Also, I am not interested in concrete speed of `toCharArray`, but in difference between these two. If one gives eg 15% performance boost, regardless the real execution time; I would go for that option.